# Magento Automatic sales category not showing products proberly

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am trying to do an automatic sales category for my magento webshop. - I have followed this tutorial: https://www.creativemgroup.com/creative-media-web-services/magento-blog/68-create-a-magento-on-sale-category-the-right-way

The php script itself works as intended, as it shows the products with specialprice/on sale  on sales category.

Problem: The product does not show the right way, the products needs to be shown as they are shown on my frontpage (With flags, shortdescription and so on)

see frontpage: Link Deleted

see salescategory: Link Deleted

I am almost sure, the problem is with the "Custom Design" xml for my category:

```
    <reference name="content">
    <remove name="product_list"/>
    <block type="catalog/product_sale" name="product_sale" alias="sale" template="catalog/product/list.phtml">
    <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
    <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
    </block>
    <action method="setLimit"><limit>32</limit></action>
    <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>3</columns></action>
    <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
    <action method="addPriceBlockType">
    <type>bundle</type>
    <block>bundle/catalog_product_price</block>
    <template>bundle/catalog/product/price.phtml</template>
    </action>
    </block>
    </reference>
    <reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultGridPerPage">
    <limit>32</limit>
    </action>
    </reference>
```

How do i get the right "Product" design for my sales category? I am not skilled in neither xml nor magento blocks

Hoping for a helping hand here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i kept searching for solutions to this problem, i came across the fact that.. maybe the php file did not bring my "custom" product-attributes to the array, from wich the product is build.

I added these attributes to the php file, and boom - everything worked like a charm. (Hopefully this will help others in my situation)

Comment: line 39 of the php file

->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','status', 'price', 'special_price', 'small_image','required_options','special_from_date', 'origin_country(Added for flags to be shown)', 'short_description(Added for short desc. to be shown)', 'maengde(Added to see weight of product)', 'special_to_date'), 'inner')